# Relate navigational property using part of PK

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

Assuming we have the following db

[image]

and we have the following classes

```
class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Control> Control { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LanguageResource> LanguageResource { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<LanguageResource>()
            .HasKey(l => new { l.LanguageResourceId, l.CultureCode });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Control>()
            .HasKey(c => c.ControlId);
    }
}
class Control
{
    public int ControlId { get; set; }
    public int LanguageResourceId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<LanguageResource> LanguageResources { get; set; }
}
class LanguageResource
{
    public int LanguageResourceId { get; set; }
    public string CultureCode { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to configure the `Context` to relate `Control.LanguageResourceId` to `LanguageResource.LanguageResourceId` to populate `Control.LanguageResources`.

I'm thinking of doing something like this.. but obviously it doesn't work.. :D

```
var control =
    context
    .Control
    .Include(c => c.LanguageResources)
    .First();

/// {
///   ControlId : 1
///   LanguageResources : [
///     {
///       LanguageResourceId : 1,
///       CultureCode : en-US
///       Text : Hello
///     },
///     {
///       LanguageResourceId : 1,
///       CultureCode : en-CA
///       Text : Hi
///     }
///   ]
/// }
```

I only have read-only access to the database so modifying the table/fields is out of the question. :)

We're using EF6 but I'd like to know if this can be done in EF Core also. :)

Comment: So a given `Control` can have many `LanguageResources`? If so, I guess your model is a little wrong.

Comment: yes. unfortunately, i do not own the db :(

Comment: So you are targeting an existing db that you don't own/can modify?

Comment: yes. read-only access

Comment: `Control` also has  PK composed as `ControlId`+ `LanguageResourceId`?

Comment: no. I edited my question to reflect our comments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182596/discussion-between-jpgrassi-and-paolo-go).

Comment: It's not possible in neither EF6 nor EF Core. Only unique keys (PK in EF6, PK and alternate key in EF Core) can be referenced by FK. Something is wrong with this entity model. Is `LanguageResource` shared between many `Control`s?